# Is there a way to set a breakpoint "at this very moment" in debug? It's about any programming language or IDE

Tags: c#, c++, c, debugging

I often debug a code by setting breakpoints. And that's where code pauses. But what if I already run for example a game in Unity3d that someone else wrote? Then I cannot easily decide where to put breakpoints, but I need to know where the programm is.
What else can you advise about advanced learning of debugging?

Comment: If you are running from source code, you can try "Pause" button.

Comment: Most debuggers support immediate halting of the debugee execution, which is probably what you're looking for. For example, hitting Ctrl+C in GDB or LLDB will interrupt the process (depending on what signal handlers are installed)

Comment: ^^ most debuggers allow such a 'Pause' or 'Break/Resume'.

Comment: I remember that in labview you can pause the execution of the program at any moment to inspect its current state

Comment: Thanks for the info! Could you please name IDEs that actually have such "Pause" ability ? Maybe links to the description?

Answer (score 1):

If your IDE has a way of pausing or breaking into the debugger, then you'll end up at some location (could be many simultaneously in a multicore environment) that is currently executing code and all others will also be halted. You can now put breakpoints anywhere you want, or just continue running and then pause / break again.

When you are in this paused state, you can look at all other threads and their callstacks to see what they are currently doing, and also switch to them to get their states.

In fact, breaking into the debugger 10 times during during 1 minute is kind-of a poor-mans profiler - you'll easily see if some part of the app is executing overly often.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any IDEs that certainly can pause?

Comment: On windows, Visual Studio is what I use and it can pause. You can also pause the execution if you debug your app through WinDbg.

Answer (score 0):

If this is windows, debuggers (and trainers) have the ability to attach to a process. Once attached, depending on the debugger, it may be able to pause the process immediately, or pause the process the next time it goes into a pending mode like waiting for something.

I've had to do something like this when debugging a multi-processing program with Visual Studio. The debugger starts off with one process, and has to be attached to the other process to switch to debug the other process.

Comment: Thanks! So the Visual Studio can? Maybe some another IDEs?

Comment: When I've used VS (Visual Studio) for a multi-process program, it's ability to attach and pause seems limited to pausing only when a thread goes to sleep waiting for something like an event. You might be better off asking about this at some gaming forum, perhaps one related to the game you're interested in.